# iPad3 video with no sound

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have iPad3, iPad2, iPad1 + all the simulators. In the app I play different types of video: m4v, mov, mp4...

The issue is: Only on iPad3 iOS 6.0.1. video plays with no sound!
The client has the same issue on iPad3!

Any ideas what is the problem?

edit:

```
if ( ![TVOutManager sharedInstance].tvoutWindow )
{
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: URL];
    player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [player setUseApplicationAudioSession:YES];

    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    CGFloat originY = 0;
    if (!currentFile.isHideToolbar)
        originY = 44;

    CGRect f = self.view.bounds;
    f.origin.y = originY;
    f.size.height -= originY;
    [player.view setFrame: f];

    [self.view addSubview: player.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.toolbar];

    [player play];
}
else
{
    [[TVOutManager sharedInstance] startVideo:URL];

    ExternalVideoControlView* exView = [[ExternalVideoControlView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024, 724)];
    exView.player = [TVOutManager sharedInstance].player;
    [self.view addSubview:exView];
}
```

Comment: lets see some code for the player.

Comment: just turn off the ipad silent mode button.....the button is at left to the ipad.check it once.and restart u r app.

Comment: Pandu1251, That was the solution! Testers gave me a silent device. And client have tested on silent device for sure...

Comment: now audio is playing with sounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just turn off the ipad silent mode button.....the button is at left to the ipad.check it once.and restart u r app.Now the audio will play with sound.